# How to Insert and Display google map via mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert object to mysql table and display that object in google map ?

Answer (score 1):

Use it as follows:

```
$mysql_data = serialize($google_map_object);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO your_table ('map_object') VALUES '$mysql_data'");
```

When retrieving it, use

```
$google_map_object = deserialize($mysql_data);
```